# When using jQuery.attr() to set an attribute the browser doesn't update the style from the css

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, attr

I have a site hat lists a set of files that can be downloaded.  The custom attribute docType is set based on the file extension.  If there is no extension the docType is set to "unknownDoc".  The CSS file looks similar to this:

```
.TitleColumn[docType="pdf"]
{
    background: url("/images/common/icons/pdf.png") no-repeat left center;
}

.TitleColumn[docType="doc"], TitleColumn[docType="docx"]
{
    background: url("/images/common/icons/word.png") no-repeat left center;
}

.TitleColumn[docType="unknownDoc"]
{
    background: url("/images/common/icons/unknownDoc.png") no-repeat left center;
}
```

It's quite possible that a user will upload a document that we don't have a css style set up for yet.  In this case the item will have a docType but no background-image.  In these cases I want the unknownDoc style to be applied.  So I use the following:

```
$('.TitleColumn').each(function (index) {
    var hasNoDocImage = $(this).css("background-image") == "none";
    var docType = $(this).attr("docType");

    if (hasNoDocImage && docType) {
        $(this).attr("docType", "unknownDoc");
        $(this).addClass("TitleColumn[docType=\"unknownDoc\"]");
    }
});
```

This works fine.  What I don't understand is why do I have to use the addClass statement?  The attr or addClass by themselves does not work.  It's as if adding the attribute doesn't cause the browser to re-style the item based on the new attribute like addClass does.  Is this a jQuery thing or a browser thing?

Is there a better way to do this?

I tried using just classes rather than the docType custom attribute but it gets too messy, especially when additional classes may be added to the element in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the great responses.  I am going to keep the code the way it is (but I could be persuaded to do differently if someone comes up with a suggestion I like better).  My reason for doing this is I really like the cleanliness of using the docType attribute.  Plus, it seems like the single .addClass line is really a fix for IE, as FF and Chrome handle it properly.  So, a one line IE fix is hardly a large issue and, these days, is quite standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to just be with IE as Chrome and FF work fine without the addClass. An easier version of yours above is:

```
$(this).attr("docType", "unknownDoc").removeClass('TitleColumn').addClass('TitleColumn');
```

Seems to be IE's inability (or jQuery's) to understand dynamic changes to selectors.

You can verify in this fiddle that FF and Chrome are fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fUSVF//

Comment: Ah, thanks.  You're right.  80% of our users still use IE so that is my first browser I test with.  After a long day of coding I think I was just in a rut and didn't think to see if this worked in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Is there a reason why I need to use removeClass?  Does addClass double up the classes in the DOM somehow, and if so, is this an issue?

Comment: addClass would not effect the element since it already has the class. removeClass followed by addClass essentially resets the class related definitions on the element and would cause any dependencies to be re-calculated (like attribute selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to change your css to:

```
.TitleColumn[docType="unknownDoc"], .unregisteredExtension
{
    background: url("/images/common/icons/unknownDoc.png") no-repeat left center;
}
```

And just `.addClass("unregisteredExtension")` after detecting this case?

```
   if (hasNoDocImage && docType) {
      $(this).addClass("unregisteredExtension")
   }
```

Comment: Ah, this is a simple idea, and I like it.  However, I really like the cleanness of the docType attribute and (call me stubborn) I don't want to mix attributes and classes for the same effect.  If I am initially working with attributes I may just stick with that.  I'm definitely open to persuasion though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not really supposed to add custom attributes. Browsers don't have to care about them - actually, ignoring them completely is the best thing they can do so ensure if you store some crap in them it won't mess anything up.

If you want to change appearance via JavaScript+CSS, use classes. The easiest way is with an element which just has no other classes, then you can simply do `$(elem).removeClass().addClass('yourNewClass');`

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation that custom attributes are a bad thing for modern browsers (FF, Chrome, IE 7+).  In fact, from what I have seen it is an intentional part of XHTML.  Unfortunately there is a good chance additional classes will be added in the future for design unrelated to the docType.  Testing to see if a docType class has been added as opposed to multiple other classes is not as trivial as one line of code.  Plus, having the docType attribute seems much cleaner.